# Sum of a random number of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

A fair coin is flipped independently until the first Heads is observed. Let the random variable  **K**  be the number of tosses until the first Heads is observed plus 1. For example, if we see **TTTHTH**, then **K=5**. For  **k=1,2,…,K** , let  $X_k$   be a continuous random variable that is uniform over the interval  **[0,5]**. The  $X_k$  are independent of one another and of the coin flips.

Let 
X=$\sum_{k=1}^k X_k$
 . Find the mean and variance of  **X** . You may use the fact that the mean and variance of a geometric random variable with parameter  **p**  are  $\frac 1p$and  ${(1−p)\over(p^2)}$ respectively.

1. What is $E[X]$?
2. What is $Var[X]$?

**My solution:**

$E[N] = \frac{1}{p} = 2$

$E[X_k] =\frac{1}{2}\times 5=\frac{5}{2}$

$E[X] = E[N]\times E[X_k]=2\times\frac{5}{2} = 5$

$Var[N]=\frac{(1−p)}{p^2} = 2$

$Var[X_k] = \frac{1}{12}\times 5^2 = \frac{25}{12}$

Comment: anyone who can help?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417264/sum-of-a-random-number-of-r-v-s#comment778680_417264.